# "Squeeze" tabulated data in pgfplotstable to fit in textwidth

Tags: pgfplotstable

is it possible to "squeeze" the text between the following columns so that the table can fit in the textwidth of the page (i.e. for the right end of the table to fall in line with the header line)?

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGLUf.png)

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{measurements.dat}
  Iter theta1    r2v    r3v      x      y BatchMode(dr2) RSLE(dr2) BatchMode(dr3) RSLE(dr3)
     1 47.3101620 0.4894206 0.3001004 1.9438193 0.6627359 0.8686121 -0.8686121 -0.9416410 -0.9416410
     2 67.1636589 0.2345960 0.2470023 1.3477526 1.3334595 0.0055472 -0.0055472 -0.0131728 -0.0131728
     3 14.9864171 0.1760000 0.2942085 1.9102333 -0.1780900 2.0172934 -2.0172934 -0.5400196 -0.5400196
     4 12.4165586 0.0431077 0.0417781 1.6252267 -0.1880540 1.7708684 -1.7708684 -0.3898872 -0.3898872
     5 79.2948875 0.0049091 0.1677193 0.7970106 1.5516762 -0.1401824 0.1401824 0.7415315 0.7415315
     6 58.4715447 0.2517404 0.4476655 1.6533368 1.2765418 0.1970344 -0.1970344 -0.3211727 -0.3211727
     7 89.1411846 0.2256854 0.0233036 0.7385122 1.5174048 -0.0116745 0.0116745 0.7788051 0.7788051
     8 29.6676051 0.4735583 0.1314127 1.8988278 -0.0272758 1.6736136 -1.6736136 -0.9533586 -0.9533586
     9 67.0925949 0.0324908 0.3494195 1.2031045 1.5047950 -0.1174309 0.1174309 0.2778978 0.2778978
    10 86.1476385 0.0191713 0.1606958 0.6199319 1.6277231 -0.0677092 0.0677092 1.0055141 1.0055141
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}


%%% Code from Dr. Christian ------ for not using headers.----------------------
\pgfkeysifdefined{/pgfplots/table/output empty row/.@cmd}{
    % upcoming releases offer this more convenient option:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
          every head row/.style={output empty row},
        }
    }
}{
    % versions up to and including 1.5.1 need this:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
            typeset cell/.append code={%
                \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=-1 %
                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
                \fi
            }
        }
    }
}

\noindent
{\scriptsize
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,empty header,
columns={Iter,theta1,r2v,r3v,x,y,BatchMode(dr2),RSLE(dr2),BatchMode(dr3),RSLE(dr3)},      % display specified columns
begin table=\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable},
columns/Iter/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=0,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/theta1/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=5,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/r2v/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=5,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/r3v/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=5,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/x/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=5,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/y/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=5,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/BatchMode(dr2)/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=5,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/RSLE(dr2)/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=5,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/BatchMode(dr3)/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=5,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/RSLE(dr3)/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=5,fixed,fixed zerofill},
every head row/.append style={before row={%
    \caption{This is a Table with Data}%
    \label{tab:DataTable}\\\toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$Iter$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\theta_{1}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$r_{2v}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$r_{3v}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$x$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$y$}  & \multicolumn{2}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering Batch Mode $(\delta r_{2})$}  & \multicolumn{2}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering RLSE Mode $(\delta r_{2})$}  & \multicolumn{2}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering Batch Mode $(\delta r_{3})$}  & \multicolumn{2}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering RLSE Mode $(\delta r_{2})$} \\ \toprule
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \multicolumn{20}{c}%
    {{\bfseries Table \thetable\ Continued from previous page}} \\
    \toprule
    %
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$Iter$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\theta_{1}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$r_{2v}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$r_{3v}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$x$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$y$}  & \multicolumn{2}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering Batch Mode $(\delta r_{2})$}  & \multicolumn{2}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering RLSE Mode $(\delta r_{2})$}  & \multicolumn{2}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering Batch Mode $(\delta r_{3})$}  & \multicolumn{2}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering RLSE Mode $(\delta r_{2})$} \\ \toprule
    \endhead
    %
    \midrule \multicolumn{20}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \bottomrule
    \endfoot
    %
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{20}{r}{{End of Table}} \\ \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    }},
]{measurements.dat}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce the padding between columns slightly by

```
begin table=\bgroup\small\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable}\egroup,
```

`\bgroup` and `\egroup` is for making this change local. Change `3pt` suitably. Also, instead of `\scriptsize` at the beginning, I have added `\small` after `\bgroup`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{measurements.dat}
  Iter theta1    r2v    r3v      x      y BatchMode(dr2) RSLE(dr2) BatchMode(dr3) RSLE(dr3)
     1 47.3101620 0.4894206 0.3001004 1.9438193 0.6627359 0.8686121 -0.8686121 -0.9416410 -0.9416410
     2 67.1636589 0.2345960 0.2470023 1.3477526 1.3334595 0.0055472 -0.0055472 -0.0131728 -0.0131728
     3 14.9864171 0.1760000 0.2942085 1.9102333 -0.1780900 2.0172934 -2.0172934 -0.5400196 -0.5400196
     4 12.4165586 0.0431077 0.0417781 1.6252267 -0.1880540 1.7708684 -1.7708684 -0.3898872 -0.3898872
     5 79.2948875 0.0049091 0.1677193 0.7970106 1.5516762 -0.1401824 0.1401824 0.7415315 0.7415315
     6 58.4715447 0.2517404 0.4476655 1.6533368 1.2765418 0.1970344 -0.1970344 -0.3211727 -0.3211727
     7 89.1411846 0.2256854 0.0233036 0.7385122 1.5174048 -0.0116745 0.0116745 0.7788051 0.7788051
     8 29.6676051 0.4735583 0.1314127 1.8988278 -0.0272758 1.6736136 -1.6736136 -0.9533586 -0.9533586
     9 67.0925949 0.0324908 0.3494195 1.2031045 1.5047950 -0.1174309 0.1174309 0.2778978 0.2778978
    10 86.1476385 0.0191713 0.1606958 0.6199319 1.6277231 -0.0677092 0.0677092 1.0055141 1.0055141
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}


%%% Code from Dr. Christian ------ for not using headers.----------------------
\pgfkeysifdefined{/pgfplots/table/output empty row/.@cmd}{
    % upcoming releases offer this more convenient option:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
          every head row/.style={output empty row},
        }
    }
}{
    % versions up to and including 1.5.1 need this:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
            typeset cell/.append code={%
                \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=-1 %
                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
                \fi
            }
        }
    }
}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,empty header,
columns={Iter,theta1,r2v,r3v,x,y,BatchMode(dr2),RSLE(dr2),BatchMode(dr3),RSLE(dr3)},      % display specified columns
begin table=\bgroup\small\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable}\egroup,
columns/Iter/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=0,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/theta1/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=5,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/r2v/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=5,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/r3v/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=5,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/x/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=5,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/y/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=5,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/BatchMode(dr2)/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=5,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/RSLE(dr2)/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=5,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/BatchMode(dr3)/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=5,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/RSLE(dr3)/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=5,fixed,fixed zerofill},
every head row/.append style={before row={%
    \caption{This is a Table with Data}%
    \label{tab:DataTable}\\\toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$Iter$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\theta_{1}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$r_{2v}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$r_{3v}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$x$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$y$}  & \multicolumn{2}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering Batch Mode $(\delta r_{2})$}  & \multicolumn{2}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering RLSE Mode $(\delta r_{2})$}  & \multicolumn{2}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering Batch Mode $(\delta r_{3})$}  & \multicolumn{2}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering RLSE Mode $(\delta r_{2})$} \\ \toprule
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \multicolumn{20}{c}%
    {{\bfseries Table \thetable\ Continued from previous page}} \\
    \toprule
    %
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$Iter$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\theta_{1}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$r_{2v}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$r_{3v}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$x$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$y$}  & \multicolumn{2}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering Batch Mode $(\delta r_{2})$}  & \multicolumn{2}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering RLSE Mode $(\delta r_{2})$}  & \multicolumn{2}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering Batch Mode $(\delta r_{3})$}  & \multicolumn{2}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering RLSE Mode $(\delta r_{2})$} \\ \toprule
    \endhead
    %
    \midrule \multicolumn{20}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \bottomrule
    \endfoot
    %
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{20}{r}{End of Table} \\ \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    }},
]{measurements.dat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You! I sincerely appreciate your time and help.  I just have one more request.  I am not sure where in the code I can have the first 6 headers line up with the word "Mode" in the other columns.  Is there an easy solution?  I bascially want to horizontally align the first 6 columns with the word "Mode".  Thanks again for your help and time.

Comment: @Joe Sure. Change all those `p{1.5cm}` to `m{1.5cm}`